# Angular routing to redirect on new server with query string

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing

Can someone help me understand how I can redirect an Angular state to a new URL with the query string parameters same as old ones?

**Example**

If my Angular application is on `http://example.com`, then all the requests to `http://example.com/dashboard?id=123&view=test` should be redirected to `http://test.com/dashboard?id=123&view=test`.

How should I define my state using the following code?

```
.state('dashboard', { 
    url: 'domain.com/dashboard', 
    controller: 'DashboardCtrl' 
})
```

I know few tricks to transfer the state to controller and then handle it from there. But I'm wondering if there's a way to redirect it through the router only to avoid repetitive code in different controllers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **A. Angular 1**

**1. main.route.js:**

```
.state('stateName', {
  url: 'dashboard',
  controller: ['$location', '$window', function ($location, $window) {
    var url = 'domainB.com';
    url += $location.$$url;
    $window.location.href = url;
  }]
})
```

> **B. Angular2/4**

**1. app.module.ts**: Declare a custom provider like:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'externalUrlResolver',
      useValue: (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => {
        window.location.href = `${route.data.externalUrl}${state.url}`;
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

**2. app-routing.module.ts**: Now using the custom provider we can redirect externally.

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: 'dashboard', component: AnyComponent,
    pathMatch: 'prefix',
    resolve: { url: 'externalUrlResolver' },
    data: { externalUrl: 'domainB.com'}
  }
]
```

**Input**

> http://domainA.com/dashboard?view=list&id=123&visible=yes

**This will be redirected to:**

> http://domainB.com/dashboard?view=list&id=123&visible=yes

Comment: Thanks @khichar.anil. This works! Accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution for this is not in Angular -- which runs in the browser after the code has already been loaded -- but on the server.  If you're using Apache, add an `.htaccess` rule that will redirect all requests for `example.com` to `test.com`.

Create a file named `.htaccess` and place it in the application root directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

If you want the redirect to be permanent (meaning browsers and search engines will remember and won't bother going to the old domain), change `302` to `301`

If this isn't a solution, you could use a [CanActivateChild guard](https://angular.io/guide/router#canactivatechild-guarding-child-routes) to indicate code that should be run before a route loads.  Add it to the routing configuration for your base route and this code will always run before components etc... are initialized. Within it, you can read the current route and redirect the user with standard JavaScript to the new domain.

Comment: I know about this server level settings but our application is on cluster right now which requires application level routing. Server is just a headless crap here.

Comment: @NitinKumar I've updated my answer with another idea

Comment: I was looking for the answer which @khichar.anil suggested above. Thanks for the answers though. Giving upvote as well in case anyone looking for server level handling unlike me.